# Exercise concerning logarithms....

Tags: logarithms

I have such a problem: find all the values of real parameter "a", for which the following inequality is true for any "x" that belongs to R.

I will show you my solution, and please can you verify whether it's right and comment . Thank you very much!

Look please, the exercise is in the left upper corner with logarithm.

[image]

Comment: Your work seems to be basically correct. You only need to take into account that $\;x^2+L\ge 0\iff \Delta\le 0\;$ , meaning: the discriminant is non-positive and not necessarily negative.

Comment: So the exercise is correct except this little nuance?

Comment: I think so, @John G.